# Golang:How to get file extension from byte slice?

Tags: go

I have a Golang Echo server which accepts arbitrary JSON payload. It's guaranteed that this payload always will have a file encoded in base64 string, but no file extension given in payload.
I want to decode this string (done), get its extension, and save this file with this extension (done). How can I get extension from decoded base64 string? Files of any type could be encoded in this string, be it .doc/.docx, .xls/.xlsx, .waff, .mp4, .ogg, etc.

Used solutions:

- `http.DetectContentType`
- `mime.ExtensionByType`
- package [`mimetype`](https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype)
- package [`filetype`](https://github.com/h2non/filetype)

Here is the code that extracts base64 string.

```golang
func (service *Inlet) getFileContentsFromPayload(payload map[string]interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    var contents []byte
    for key, value := range payload {
        switch value.(type) {
        case string:
            decoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(value.(string))
            if err != nil {
                continue
            } else {
                contents = decoded
                delete(payload, key)
                break
            }
        default:
            continue
        }
    }
    // just to check that encoded file is here.
    if contents == nil {
        service.logger.Println("No b64-encoded file given.")
        return nil, echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusBadRequest, "Please provide base64-encoded file.")
    }
    return contents, nil
}
```

Next the returned byte slice goes to this function which saves the file locally:

```golang
func (service *Inlet) prepareNFSData(contents []byte) (*os.File, error) {
    kind, err := filetype.Match(contents)
    if err != nil {
        service.logger.Println(err)
        return nil, echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusBadRequest, map[string]interface{}{
            "description": "Unknown extension given.",
            "reason":      err.Error(),
        })
    }
    filename := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s.%s",
        uuid.New().String(),
        kind.Extension,
    )
    file, err := service.createFile(contents, filename)
    if err != nil {
        service.logger.Println(err)
        return nil, echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Internal server error.")
    }
    return file, nil
}
```

Here used the last solution `filetype` package with `Match` function which should return `Type` struct that contains info about MIME type and file extension. I need to remove this line of code.

```golang
kind, err := filetype.Match(contents)
if err != nil {
    service.logger.Println(err)
    return nil, echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusBadRequest, map[string]interface{}{
        "description": "Unknown extension given.",
        "reason":      err.Error(),
    })
}
```

with another solution of getting file extension from byte slice. These solutions don't work for most of test file samples.

Comment: The standard lib doesn't provide a better solution than this. If this isn't sufficient, that leaves you looking for another 3rd party lib, which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I am going to link the first thing i got from Google: [content filetype] (https://golangcode.com/get-the-content-type-of-file/) . I am aware that this actually checks what filetype it is instead of reading the extension to the filename.